# Error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" en una expresión regular de PHP

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un codigo que me lanza el siguiente error:

> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.

Este es el codigo:

```
$cadena = 'Hola mi codigo es 987128 mi Nombre es Juan y Mi contraseña es #Juans16';

if(preg_match('Hola mi codigo es '."/[0-9]/".' mi Nombre es '."/[a-zA-Z]/".' y Mi contraseña es '."/[a-zA-Z0-9\#]/",$cadena)){
    echo "Ok";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

He estado leyendo en otros foros y sé que tiene que ver con los delimitadores, pero no sé cuáles: todos están con las barras normales.

El fin del código es que me evalúe si lo que está en la variable **$cadena** cumpla con lo que se pide con las expresiones regulares, que por ejemplo, si en el **codigo** de la persona se coloca una letra, me lance "No" y así.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estás indicando la expresión regular de forma adecuada: **el patrón debes darlo todo él dentro de un delimitador** (`/`, `#` o [el que sea](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)). Y una vez dentro de él, expresas las expresiones regulares de forma normal, sin anidar más delimitadores (es decir, sin otro `/`, `#` o lo que sea).

En esencia, lo que debes hacer es:

```
preg_match("/patrón/","cadena")
```

Es decir, en tu caso:

```
$patron = "/Hola mi codigo es [0-9]+ mi Nombre es [a-zA-Z]+ y Mi contraseña es [a-zA-Z0-9#]+/";
```

Simplificando, en tu caso estabas diciendo algo así como:

```
$patron = "algo /[0-9]/ y otro algo";  // ¡INCORRECTO!
//              ^     ^
```

cuando debería ser:

```
$patron = "/algo [0-9]/";
//         ^          ^
```

Comment: Vi tu edición y no pensé que estuvieras respondiendo. Buena respuesta!

Comment: Y en caso de que quiera detectar una barra? "/" Como haría? Porque hago ésto **[a-zA-Z0-9&/]** pero lo que le sigue cambia de color.

Comment: @Jalkhov escápala: `[a-zA-Z0-9&\/]`.

Comment: @fedorqui Bien, resuelto. Me puedes explicar mejor cuando se debe colocar el simbolo "+"?

Comment: @Jalkhov `+` se refiere a que quieres que algo suceda una o muchas veces: `[0-9]+` coincidirá con 23, 1 o 23423424. Luego tienes `*` para que coincida ninguna, una o muchas veces. Por tanto, `[0-9]*` coincidirá con "" (nada), 23, 1 o 232342.

Comment: @fedorqui Disculpa no haberlo consultado con el anterior comentario pero ahora es que me surge la duda, como hago para que detecte los espacios? O no se necesida colocar algo?

Comment: @Jalkhov un espacio es un espacio... lo escribes y ya está :) Si tienes nuevas dudas, [formula una nueva pregunta](/questions/ask), ¡es gratis!

Comment: @Jalkhov fíjate que había puesto comillas. Mariano indicó que no era correcto, así que las eliminé.

Answer (score 3):

> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.

Significa que PHP está esperando un delimitador al inicio y al final del regex (antes de cualquier flag), y no se está pasando correctamente. Popularmente se usan `/`s para delimitar, pero puede ser cualquier caracter que no sea alfanumérico ni `\`. Esto está explicado en: [Delimitadores (manual de PHP)](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Ejemplo:

```
/regex/is
```

- `/` son los delimitadores (aunque podríamos haber usado cualquier otro símbolo)
- `regex` es el patrón
- `is` son los modificadores

Esto significa que, dentro del patrón hay que escapar cada `/` que se quiera usar como literal:

```
/Ejemplo\/s/
```

O usar otro delimitador para no tener que escaparlo:

```
~Ejemplo/s~
```

---

**En tu caso**

`preg_match()` acepta una expresión regular como parámetro. Pero es **un** regex en total, no se puede armar por partes.

Si usamos `/` como delimitador, el regex que estás intentando pasar, debería ser:

```
if(preg_match('/Hola mi codigo es [0-9]+ mi Nombre es [a-zA-Z]+ y Mi contraseña es [a-zA-Z0-9#]+/',$cadena)){
    echo "Ok";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

- Fijate que agregué el `+` después de cada clase de caracteres para repetirlo 1 o más veces
- Además, probablemente te interese anclarlo al inicio y al final del string con `^` y `$`

Comment: ¡Grande! Respondiendo descubrí que puede haber otro delimitadores que `/`.

Comment: @fedorqui es un punto a favor de PHP. De hecho, los delimitadores son propios del lenguaje, y no se pasan al motor de regex. En PHP sirven exclusivamente para poder pasar los modificadores.

Comment: Interesante y utilísimo. En Sed puede serlo cualquier carácter menos la contrabarra o el salto de línea :O ([referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33914546/1983854)).

Comment: @fedorqui esa es la sintaxis de Perl, que acepta cualquiera si sigue a `s` o `m`, o únicamente `/` cuando no se usa `m` (de ahí el origen de que `/` sea el más usado). JavaScript sólo acepta `/`s, .Net no usa delimitadores... Depende de cada lenguaje.